# Proving an onto function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)$ is onto.

The method I know is to find $x$ in terms of $y$ and then check it. But clearly it's not one one and hence not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the fact that every cubic equation has at least one real solution.